# Insert com erro SQLSTATE [HY093]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou fazendo um formulário para salvar dados na base de dados e da esse erro `Erro SQLSTATE [HY093]`

```
<?PHP 
$nome = $_REQUEST['Nome'];
$cpf = $_REQUEST['CPF'];
$sexo = $_REQUEST['Sexo'];
$datanasc = $_REQUEST['DataNasc'];
$telefone = $_REQUEST['Telefone'];
$cidade = $_REQUEST['Cidade'];
$bairro = $_REQUEST['Bairro'];
$nomedarua = $_REQUEST['NomedaRua'];
$numerocasa = $_REQUEST['NumeroCasa'];
$complemento = $_REQUEST['Complemento'];
$email = $_REQUEST['Email'];
$senha = $_REQUEST['Senha'];


if(isset($_REQUEST['btnincluir']))
{
try{
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=consultorio','root','');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO cliente VALUES(:idcliente,:Nome,:CPF,:Sexo,:DataNasc,:Telefone,:Cidade,:Bairro,:NomedaRua,:NumeroCasa,:Complemento,:Email,:Senha)');
$stmt->execute(array(':Nome' =>$nome,':CPF' =>$cpf,':Sexo' =>$sexo,':DataNasc' =>$datanasc,':Telefone' =>$telefone,':Cidade' =>$cidade,':Bairro' =>$bairro,':NomedaRua' =>$nomedarua,':NumeroCasa' =>$numerocasa,':Complemento' =>$complemento,':Email' =>$email,':Senha' =>$senha));
echo $stmt-> rowCount();
}catch(PDOException $e){
echo 'Erro '.$e->getMessage();
}}
?>
```

Form

```
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" name="cliente" action="valida.php">
    <h1>CADASTRO DE CLIENTES ODONTOCENTER</h1>
    <br>
    <p>id:
      <input type="text" name="idcliente" readonly>
    </p>
    <p>Nome:
      <input type="text" name="Nome">
    </p>
    <p>CPF:
      <input type="text" name="CPF">
    </p>
    <p>Sexo
      <input type="radio" name="Sexo" value="M">M
      <input type="radio" name="Sexo" value="F">F
      <p>
        <p>Data de Nascimento:
          <input type="text" name="DataNasc">
        </p>
        <p>Telefone:
          <input type="text" name="Telefone">
        </p>
        <p>Cidade:
          <input type="text" name="Cidade">
        </p>
        <p>Bairro:
          <input type="text" name="Bairro">
        </p>
        <p>Rua:
          <input type="text" name="NomedaRua">
        </p>
        <p>Número:
          <input type="text" name="NumeroCasa">
        </p>
        <p>Complemento:
          <input type="text" name="Complemento">
        </p>
        <p>Email:
          <input type="text" name="Email">
        </p>
        <p>Senha:
          <input type="password" name="Senha">
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Incluir" name="btnincluir">
          <input type="submit" value="Alterar" name="btnalterar">
          <input type="submit" value="Excluir" name="btnexcluir">
        </p>
  </form>
</body>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom dia cara. Se for um registro novo, pode começar por remover :idcliente que o PDO e MySQL cuida disso sozinho. Certifique-se também que está enviando para seu banco de dados a mesma quantidade de colunas que lá tem.

Comment: Provavavelmente o erro é, existe uma bind a mais declarado e  um a menos informado. Como o MarcosVinicius disse remova o `:idcliente` do insert.

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO cliente VALUES(:idcliente,:Nome,:CPF,:Sexo,:DataNasc,:Telefone,:Cidade,:Bairro,:NomedaRua,:NumeroCasa,:Complemento,:Email,:Senha)');
```

Retire o :idcliente.

No VALUES, você está passando todos os registros da tabela. E nos seus parâmetros não existe o valor para :idcliente, sendo assim existem menos parâmetros que o esperado.

Obs.: Certifique-se que na tabela o idcliente seja auto increment.